# Rails Paperclip inserting instead of updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, simple-form

I created a simple application that has a Product and an Image model. Product has_many Images and Images has an attached file attribute (paperclip).

I created a simple_form for creating/editing Products and it works fine on creation. However, when editing a Product that has N images, rails inserts more N files - empty files.

I have set up a Simple Form custom input that tests if the image attachment exists in which case instead of rendering the builders input, it only renders an image_tag().

I see the html generated and it show something strange, a hidden tag:

```
<input id="product_images_attributes_0_id" name="product[images_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="14">
```

And in the rails server console I see:

```
Processing by ProductsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"asdfasdfaasdf=", "product"=>{"reference"=>"Y1112CYL.E2", "images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"14"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Product", "id"=>"20"}
  Product Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "20"]]
Unpermitted parameters: id
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "images" ("created_at", "imageable_id", "imageable_type", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 18 Feb 2014 05:05:13 UTC +00:00], ["imageable_id", 20], ["imageable_type", "Product"], ["updated_at", Tue, 18 Feb 2014 05:05:13 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
```

Here is the code to my implementation. If someone could help I would be very happy! Please pardon me if I left out any import part of the code, I will gladly edit the question to include it.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@product) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.input :reference %>
    <h3>Images</h3>
    <div id='images'>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :images do |image| %>
        <%= render 'image_fields', :f => image %>
      <% end %>
      <div class='links'>
        <%= link_to_add_association 'New image', f, :images %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

_image_fields.html.erb

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: "nested-fields images-fields" do %>
    <%= content_tag :div, id: "new-image" do %>
        <% if f.object.photo.exists? %>
            <% f.template.image_tag(f.object.photo.url(:thumb)) %>
        <% else %>
            <% f.input :photo, :as => :photo %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

app/inputs/photo_input.erb

```
class PhotoInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::FileInput  
  def input
    out = '' # the output string we're going to build
    # check if there's an uploaded file (eg: edit mode or form not saved)
    if object.send("#{attribute_name}?")
      # append preview image to output
      # <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb), :class => 'thumbnail', id: 'avatar' %>
      out << template.image_tag(object.send(attribute_name).url(:thumb), :class => 'thumbnail', id: 'photo')
    else
      # append file input. it will work accordingly with your simple_form wrappers
      (out << @builder.file_field(attribute_name, input_html_options)).html_safe
    end
  end
end
```

ProductsController#update

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Perhaps adding a condition on nested_attributes that ignores if attributes are empty? Are the images shown in the view at least from your `image_fields` partial?

Comment: Hey! That seems to have solved it. I added: :reject_if => :all_blank.

Comment: As per my answer below, this solves the question, but creates an issue with destroy.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, @omarvelous' comment seems to have solved it:

I added the reject if all blank to my accepts_nested_attributes_for

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank
```

Edit:
It turns out there is an issue with this solution. When reject_if => :all_blank is it stops the destroy from working properly. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766299/paperclip-problem-for-accepts-nested-attributes-for-and-reject-if) that shows a workaround -- that I did not manage to get to work.